# Sqrt function makes 8kb place on flash memory of stm32

Tags: gcc, arm, stm32, stm32cubeide

I'm developing stm32f030fp6 on stm32cubeIde but when I need to use sqrt, it takes about 8 kb in flash, I have this problem with sprintf function too, I searched more but there is no answer, is there anyone to help me?

this is the code with sqrt:
[image: this is the code with sqrt]

this is the code without sqrt:
[image: this is the code without sqrt]

Comment: What exactly is wrong? Square root is not a trivial function. I think it might be ok. You have its source code, take a look. You may be able to cut things off it.

Comment: Actually the problem is not only with that, When I try to use any builtin arm standard library its like that, for example when i'm using sqrt of arm it takes about 8 kb flash and when try to use sprintf it takes about 30kb of flash

Comment: I have a feeling, that's how much those functions actually take space.

Comment: why is like that? do you know? in keil I used them and that is not like stm32cubeide

Comment: If you import the same code/library, it should take just as much space (well, that's actually up to compiler, but the difference can't be too huge). Something else is being pulled with it then. Unfortunately, I'm not the right person to say anything specific about that, maybe someone else will help.

Comment: Please share/indicate the exect code segments/lines that cause high flash usage.

Comment: I added an image @Tagli

Comment: soft floating point is bad to use on an mcu.  C functions in general as well but the absolute worst function to use is any form of printf, it sucks in so much library that it explodes the size of the binary.   this is known and expected.  if you want to save that space then do neither, use fixed point for the math and make your own printf equivalent routines and use as little C library as possible.  Otherwise spend more money for a larger mcu.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you might be ended up with *double* libraries instead of *float* ones. Check your function symbols using map file or IDE and look for suspicious functions. BTW, CMSIS DSP has a *sqrt* function, which supports fixed point math and may be cheaper even when using floats.